# How to convert 8G DVD into 4G

Tags: dvd, conversion

I have an 8G DVD disc/DVD image which I have to convert to 4G format. Is there any application that -maybe by reducing quality- can make this conversion?
I need a Windows solution.

Comment: windows ? linux ? mac ? 

etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DVD Shrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/).

[Here](http://www.mrbass.org/dvdshrink/) is an illustrative guide.

Answer (score 0):

I use Nero Recode. It is one of the tools that comes in Nero Burning ROM.